# win32 I/O performance issues

Tags: c++, winapi, io

I have a problem with win32 I/O performance:
I'm trying to achieve a decent writing speed using OpenFile/WriteFile.
Using Resource Monitor (it comes with windows) I measured the writing speed of the following piece of code and I found that it is writing at 2MB/sec...

```
HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
hFile = CreateFile(
    L"test",
    (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE),
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_ALWAYS,
    (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL |
    FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH |
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING),
    NULL);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    //OK
    unsigned long bytesWritten = 0;
    unsigned long* Buffer = (unsigned long*)malloc(4096*sizeof(unsigned long));
    ZeroMemory(Buffer, 4096); //thanks to 'bash.d'
    while (true)
    {
        /*the infinite loop is intentional
          because I wanted to see if the writing speed of 2MB/sec
          was right */
        WriteFile(hFile,
            Buffer,
            4096,
            &bytesWritten,
            NULL);
        if (bytesWritten <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with the following and it's the same...

```
hFile = CreateFile(
    L"test",
    (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE),
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_ALWAYS,
    (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
```

What am I doing wrong(about the writing speed) ? and how can I improve the writing speed ?
Thank you and sorry for my english

Edit:
I'm writing on a local disk

Comment: What are you doing wrong about what? To improve the writing speed you can try make a bigger buffer than 4 KiB, but this ultimately depends on the OS.

Comment: Smallish 4k buffer OK, but 2MB/s still seems apallingly slow for a local disk.   Of course, if the disk is on a slow/congested network...

Comment: Hint: use [**ZeroMemory**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366920(VS.85).aspx) to initialize your buffer.

Comment: WriteFile will always want to wait for fairies. Be it a full cache or  I/O congestion. Use WriteFileEx and just do it async. And when Windows tells you "there's a cache", it doesn't mean it'll consider using it.

Comment: Nah, sounds entirely reasonable that your speed is around 2MB/sec when only writing files using a 4kb buffer. Most modern disk have on-board buffers of several MB. Using a bench-marker I have here, I get 1,687kb/sec on an aspire laptop(320gb 2.5", win7), 2,415kb/s on a QuadCore desktop (80gb 3.5", winXP), 534kb/s on a P3 (60gb 3.5",winXP). Compare these figures to the same systems with a file-size of 10,240kb. We then get 298,542kb/s 27,075kb/s 25,884kb/s respectively. Moral of the story - don't try to write large amounts of data with lots of small writes.

Comment: FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH/FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING causes bypass of all buffering in Windows.  It should be faster without this, though your scenario may require these flags for some reason. Note that as it stands, your `Buffer` and `ZeroMemory` are not using the same size.

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting, and similar to an issue I have, and can reproduce on 2 different servers with Windows Server 2003 SP2 64-bit (single hard drives, not RAID).  Simply doing a WriteFile() of 36 bytes and then 99964 bytes in a loop produces similar behavior (I'm guessing it would be the same with a single write, and some other versions of Windows; that's just what I happened to be using).  CPU usage starts off very low, and then increases gradually -- on one server, the test was around 50% CPU usage at around 175GB (about 95% of that is kernel time; 60% in my program and 40% in 'System').

You may also try async IO to get the test performance. That is opening the file with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED and using the LPOVERLAPPED argument of WriteFile. You may or may not get better performance with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. You will have to test to see.

FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING will generally give you more consistent speeds and better streaming behavior, and it avoids polluting your disk cache with data that you may not need again, but it isn't necessarily faster overall.

You should also test to see what the best size is for each block of IO. In my experience There is a huge performance difference between copying a file 4k at a time and copying it 1Mb at a time.

In my past testing of this (a few years ago) I found that block sizes below about 64kB were dominated by overhead, and total throughput continued to improve with larger block sizes up to about 512KB. I wouldn't be surprised if with today's drives you needed to use block sizes larger than 1MB to get maximum throughput.

The numbers you are currently using appear to be reasonable, but may not be optimal. Also I'm fairly certain that FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH prevents the use of the on-disk cache and thus will cost you a fair bit of performance.

It would be of worth to try below thing...

1) Enabling FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN flag

2) "Enable advanced performance" in "Disk Policies" in the Device Manager

3) Varying disk chunk size from 64 KB to 4096 ...

4) Try FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING

Comment: async I/O will probably make things slower with WRITE_THROUGH/NO_BUFFERING - async will help if you are allowing the OS to buffer the data, meaning more (buffered) writes can be done before the earlier ones are committed to media.  I am also curious why SEQUENTIAL_SCAN would help with write performance?

Comment: That article does not mention writing anywhere, this flag affects read performance

Answer (score 0):

1. [Use async IO bound to a completion port](http://rusanu.com/2008/11/11/high-performance-windows-programs/)
2. Pre-grow the file using [SetFileValidData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. Open the handle with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`

A consumer grade drive (even 5400RPM) should be able to write ~130MB/sec (single spindle, no raid). No other IO should occur at the same time (no head movement).

See https://github.com/rusanu/writing-a-binary-file-in-c-very-fast for an example.